# How to check a number every x amount

Tags: javascript, algorithm, conditional-statements

I need to write a conditional statement for a cloud function that runs every 2016th document created.

So I have a variable that gets iterated on every time a new document is created. In my mind I thought I would be able to use this one variable to check every x amount.

The current amount of `documentsCreated` is just a random number, not a set variable.

```
const documentsCreated = 19239123;

function checkDocuments(){
    let x = (documentsCreated / 2016) % 2016;
    if(x === 2016){
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
}
```

This function should return `true` everytime `documentsCreated` is a multiple of 2016.

I would love to do this with just one variable but I am thinking that I might have to keep a second variable that I reset to 0 every time it hits 2016.

Comment: `documentsCreated % 2016` will return 0 for integer multiples of 2016. Assuming 0 should return false, then `return !(documentsCreated  && documentsCreated % 2016)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check if mod, when dividing, is equal to 0.

```
 const documentsCreated = 19239123;

    function checkDocuments(){
        let x = documentsCreated % 2016;
        if(x === 0){
          return true
        } else {
          return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much. This is exactly what I was after. Not sure what I was thinking trying to use modulo like that.